# How can I find a Bitcoin address from the transaction time and amount?

Tags: blockchain

If I know the time of the transaction down to the minute and the amount of Bitcoin, how can I find the transaction id (or transaction ids, assuming there is more than one)?

Is there an online blockchain query tool that will let me do this? I really don't want to have to download the whole blockchain and run code against that.

What would be the easiest way for me to get this info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this: https://goochain.net/

It has options for date range and amount range.